Mystery sequence: F C R B C B O T B
Here is a sequence.  What letter comes next?
F, C, R, B, C, B, O, T, B, ...
I expect it will take some time to answer this.

These are the

 First letters of the last ten US presidents' last names:
 38   Gerald  Rudolph Ford
 39   Jimmy   Earl    Carter
 40   Ronald  Wilson  Reagan
 41   George  Herbert Walker  Bush
 42   Bill    Jefferson   Clinton
 43   George  Walker  Bush
 44   Barack  Hussein Obama
 45   Donald  John    Trump
 46   Joe Robinette   Biden


 The next president has not yet been elected, so it will take "some time" before the sequence continues...


So fast!  OK, you get the mark.  I will not require to fill in the actual answer.
